# Django: complex order by and filter by from many relations query with nested models

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-filter

**What I want to achieve:**
I want list of

```
[
  {
    "location":"Loc 1",
    "session":[
      {
        "start":"2021-01-01",
        "counts":600,
        "details":[
          {
            "id":13,
            "length_max":21,
            "length_min":15,
            "length_avg":16,
            "length_std":19,
            "is_active":false,
            "type":"dog"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "location":"Loc3",
    "session":[
      {
        "start":"2021-01-01",
        "counts":500,
        "details":[
          {
            "id":15,
            "length_max":19,
            "length_min":16,
            "length_avg":16,
            "length_std":19,
            "is_active":false,
            "type":"dog"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

**My Viewset is**

```
class SessionFilter(FilterSet):
    type_filter = filters.CharFilter(method="filter_by_type")
    

    def filter_by_type(self,queryset,name,value):
        queryset = queryset.filter(session__details__type=value).distinct()
        return queryset

class SessionModelViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Session.objects.all()
    serializer_class = SessionSerializers
    filter_backends = (DjangoFilterBackend,)
    filter_class = SessionFilter
```

I am trying to filter based on type, but am not able to fetch what I need.
The out I am getting is

```
[
  {
    "location":"Loc 1",
    "session":[
      {
        "start":"2021-01-01",
        "counts":600,
        "details":[
          {
            "id":13,
            "length_max":21,
            "length_min":15,
            "length_avg":16,
            "length_std":19,
            "is_active":false,
            "type":"dog"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "start":"2021-01-01",
        "counts":600,
        "details":[
          {
            "id":7,
            "length_max":39,
            "length_min":25,
            "length_avg":25,
            "length_std":27,
            "is_active":true,
            "type":"cat"
          },
          {
            "id":19,
            "length_max":39,
            "length_min":25,
            "length_avg":25,
            "length_std":27,
            "is_active":false,
            "type":"cat"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "location":"Loc3",
    "session":[
      {
        "start":"2021-01-01",
        "counts":500,
        "details":[
          {
            "id":15,
            "length_max":19,
            "length_min":16,
            "length_avg":16,
            "length_std":19,
            "is_active":false,
            "type":"dog"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "start":"2021-01-01",
        "counts":500,
        "details":[
          {
            "id":9,
            "length_max":39,
            "length_min":25,
            "length_avg":25,
            "length_std":27,
            "is_active":true,
            "type":"cat"
          },
          {
            "id":21,
            "length_max":39,
            "length_min":25,
            "length_avg":25,
            "length_std":27,
            "is_active":false,
            "type":"cat"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

How can I customise the filter or change the nested query to fetch the desired output and how can I order by id. Till the second nested level, I am able to fetch data (maybe it is not complicated) but in the 3rd level, I am facing this issue.

**Model.py**

```
class Place(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'place'
        managed=False
        
        
class Session(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    place = models.ForeignKey(Place,related_name='session',on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    start = models.DateField(auto_now=True)
    counts = models.IntegerField()

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'session'
        managed=False


class Animal(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    sess = models.ForeignKey(Session,related_name='details',on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    type = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    is_active = models.BooleanField()
    length_max = models.IntegerField()
    length_min = models.IntegerField()
    length_avg = models.IntegerField()
    length_std = models.IntegerField()

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'animal'
        managed=False
```

**serializer.py**

```
class AnimalSerializers(FlexFieldsModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Animal
        fields = ["id","length_max","length_min","length_avg","length_std","is_active","type"]


class SessionSerializers(FlexFieldsModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Session
        fields = ["start","counts","details"]
        expandable_fields = {
          'details': (AnimalSerializers, {'many': True})
        }


class PlaceSerializers(FlexFieldsModelSerializer):
  class Meta:
      model = Place
      fields = ["location","session"]
      expandable_fields = {
        'session': (SessionSerializers, {'many': True})
      }
```

After prefetch I am getting the json format as

```
{
        "location": "Loc 2",
        "session": [
            {
                "start": "2021-01-01",
                "counts": 300,
                "details": [
                    {
                        "id": 14,
                        "length_max": 22,
                        "length_min": 16,
                        "length_avg": 16,
                        "length_std": 19,
                        "is_active": true,
                        "type": "dog"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "start": "2021-01-01",
                "counts": 300,
                "details": []
            }
        ]
    }
```

is there a way to eliminate and fetch the only one which is required?

After using with filter method, the obtained json format is

```
.prefetch_related(
    Prefetch('session', queryset=Session.objects.filter(details__type=value)),
    Prefetch('session__details', queryset=Details.objects.all().order_by('id'))),
)


[
    {
        "location": "Loc 3",
        "session": [
            {
                "start": "2021-01-01",
                "counts": 500,
                "details": [
                    {
                        "id": 15,
                        "length_max": 19,
                        "length_min": 16,
                        "length_avg": 16,
                        "length_std": 19,
                        "is_active": false,
                        "type": "dog"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "location": "Loc 4",
        "session": [
            {
                "start": "2021-01-02",
                "counts": 800,
                "details": [
                    {
                        "id": 1,
                        "length_max": 24,
                        "length_min": 18,
                        "length_avg": 25,
                        "length_std": 27,
                        "is_active": false,
                        "type": "cat"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 4,
                        "length_max": 24,
                        "length_min": 18,
                        "length_avg": 25,
                        "length_std": 27,
                        "is_active": false,
                        "type": "cat"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 16,
                        "length_max": 24,
                        "length_min": 18,
                        "length_avg": 16,
                        "length_std": 19,
                        "is_active": false,
                        "type": "dog"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "start": "2021-01-02",
                "counts": 800,
                "details": [
                    {
                        "id": 10,
                        "length_max": 29,
                        "length_min": 16,
                        "length_avg": 16,
                        "length_std": 19,
                        "is_active": false,
                        "type": "dog"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 22,
                        "length_max": 29,
                        "length_min": 16,
                        "length_avg": 16,
                        "length_std": 19,
                        "is_active": false,
                        "type": "dog"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
```

Output after updating the code

```
 [
    {
        "location": "Loc 1",
        "session": [
            {
                "start": "2021-01-01",
                "counts": 600,
                "details": [
                    {
                        "id": 13,
                        "length_max": 21,
                        "length_min": 15,
                        "length_avg": 16,
                        "length_std": 19,
                        "is_active": false,
                        "type": "dog"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "location": "Loc 2",
        "session": [
            {
                "start": "2021-01-01",
                "counts": 300,
                "details": [
                    {
                        "id": 14,
                        "length_max": 22,
                        "length_min": 16,
                        "length_avg": 16,
                        "length_std": 19,
                        "is_active": true,
                        "type": "dog"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "location": "Loc 3",
        "session": [
            {
                "start": "2021-01-01",
                "counts": 500,
                "details": [
                    {
                        "id": 15,
                        "length_max": 19,
                        "length_min": 16,
                        "length_avg": 16,
                        "length_std": 19,
                        "is_active": false,
                        "type": "dog"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "location": "Loc 4",
        "session": [
            {
                "start": "2021-01-02",
                "counts": 800,
                "details": [
                    {
                        "id": 16,
                        "length_max": 24,
                        "length_min": 18,
                        "length_avg": 16,
                        "length_std": 19,
                        "is_active": false,
                        "type": "dog"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "start": "2021-01-02",
                "counts": 800,
                "details": [
                    {
                        "id": 10,
                        "length_max": 29,
                        "length_min": 16,
                        "length_avg": 16,
                        "length_std": 19,
                        "is_active": false,
                        "type": "dog"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 22,
                        "length_max": 29,
                        "length_min": 16,
                        "length_avg": 16,
                        "length_std": 19,
                        "is_active": false,
                        "type": "dog"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "location": "Loc 5",
        "session": [
            {
                "start": "2021-01-02",
                "counts": 400,
                "details": [
                    {
                        "id": 17,
                        "length_max": 28,
                        "length_min": 19,
                        "length_avg": 16,
                        "length_std": 19,
                        "is_active": true,
                        "type": "dog"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "start": "2021-01-02",
                "counts": 400,
                "details": [
                    {
                        "id": 11,
                        "length_max": 38,
                        "length_min": 28,
                        "length_avg": 16,
                        "length_std": 19,
                        "is_active": false,
                        "type": "dog"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 23,
                        "length_max": 38,
                        "length_min": 28,
                        "length_avg": 16,
                        "length_std": 19,
                        "is_active": true,
                        "type": "dog"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "location": "Loc 6",
        "session": [
            {
                "start": "2021-01-02",
                "counts": 450,
                "details": [
                    {
                        "id": 18,
                        "length_max": 35,
                        "length_min": 26,
                        "length_avg": 16,
                        "length_std": 19,
                        "is_active": false,
                        "type": "dog"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "start": "2021-01-02",
                "counts": 450,
                "details": [
                    {
                        "id": 12,
                        "length_max": 15,
                        "length_min": 13,
                        "length_avg": 16,
                        "length_std": 19,
                        "is_active": true,
                        "type": "dog"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 24,
                        "length_max": 15,
                        "length_min": 13,
                        "length_avg": 16,
                        "length_std": 19,
                        "is_active": false,
                        "type": "dog"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Comment: Can you share your serializer and models?

Comment: Anyway you can try to add a prefetch with a filtered queryset like this: `.prefetch_related(Prefetch('session__details', queryset=Details.objects.filter(type=value).order_by('id')))`

Comment: @bdbd, Thank you for the quick response. It helped me. But, now the data is displayed with the previous stage, with empty next stage data.

Comment: @bdbd, won't the order work if it is made on a lower stage id? Because that part didn't work. Please suggest to me, if there is any other option on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this:

```
.prefetch_related(
    Prefetch('session', queryset=Session.objects.filter(details__type=value)),
    Prefetch('session__details', queryset=Details.objects.filter(type=value).order_by('id'))),
)
```

This will remove all sessions which don't have details that have the value you are looking for, and will sort all the details within those sessions by their ids.

Comment: thanks again, the above one worked fine for the first 3 datasets, from the 4th dataset, filtered and non filtered data both came. The sorting also didn't work as expected.

Comment: I updated my answer to also filter `Details` in `session__details`. Can you try again?

Comment: Also did you want to order by session or by detail?

Comment: It seems to be ordered already. Or did you want it descending?

Comment: I am trying in ascending order only, for the first 4 numbers i.e 13,14,15,16 ids are ordered, after that it is not. The filter is working as expected, not order by.

Comment: I don't get it? Can you show all the data you have right now and update the question

Comment: Ok and with my latest answer, what is the exact output you get?

Comment: Order by is applied to the first set of data and not ordered from complete data. I have attached the complete output data in the last section.

Comment: Actually the output is expected. The details are ordered per session. You cant order them all together because some belong to different sessions.

Comment: Okay, thank you for the code and explaination

Comment: Is this answer still relevant? If so, please do [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/1027465) this answer

Comment: is there a way to use Sum, Min, Max and std deviation on the integer columns from session and details and group by based on other columns?

Comment: In loc 4, loc 5, and loc 6 there are two different counts and other integer columns from details, is there a way to do aggregate functions on these? I tried to annotate and aggregate in a queryset of view, but it is not fetching the output I want.

Comment: Yes it should be possible by adding annotations inside the queryset in `Prefetch`. But I think that should be in another question so we can keep this thread short.

Comment: Okay, I am posting a new question then, please help me, if you have the answer.

Comment: Sure. And hopefully others can help. Just describe exactly what kind of annotation you need for which fields

Comment: I have posted a new question, please check and if possible help me https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68544303/django-aggregate-functions-on-nested-query-many-to-many-relationship
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68546303/django-temporary-table-or-views-to-create-flattened-json